# Laravel Data passing from view to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass data from a view file to a controller file. The purpose is to show the user the previous data at the time of edit the record. My view file contains this code:

```
<a href="{{ route('feestype.edit', $feesType) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

I called the dd method before passing it to the controller. Here is the result of dd:

```
  FeesType {#287 ▼
  #table: "fees_types"
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:5 [▶]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

When I receive the object in the controller file it shows this result on dd:

```
FeesType {#283 ▼
  #table: "fees_types"
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

The problem is the connection variable returns a null in controller but in view it returns my current connection database: mysql.
Here is my controller file's edit method:

```
public function edit(FeesType $feesType)
{
    //
    //$feesType = FeesType::find($feesType->id);
    dd($feesType);
    return view('feestype.edit',['feesType'=>$feesType]);
}
```

and here is my route definition:

```
Route::resource('feestype','FeesTypesController');
```

I don't know the reason behind this. Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: What do you mean by the `connection  variable returns a null`?  What is the connection variable you're talking about?  I think I see... so you're only issue here is `$feesType->connection` is null?

Comment: the json #connection instance of the dd result

Comment: "I need to pass data from a view file to a controller file", you're working backwards - that's not how things work. Might be worth while considering updating your question with what the goal actually is because you've got a lot of information that contradicts whatever it is you're trying to accomplish, ie: You have a lot of code that has nothing to do with passing data from a controller to a view.

Comment: Dear friend, I don't understand your answer. Please let me know what is not clear to you

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment asking you to clarify what it is you want to accomplish because your current description is conflicting with the code you have shared. Why are you trying to fetch database connection information? That's got nothing to do with this equation.

Comment: the main problem is I don't find an object in the controller file;s edit method. the edit method contains a null parameter though I passed that parameter from the view file

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

**ROUTE**

```
<a href="{{ route('feestype.edit', $feesType->id) }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $feesType = \App\FeesType::find($id);
    dd($feesType);
    return view('feestype.edit',['feesType'=>$feesType]);
}
```